# REACT JS: Uncaught TypeError: window.jwplayer is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwplayer

I am trying to integrate JW Player in my react project and having the above error in console.
This is what I am trying in code using the [article](https://medium.com/@suhag_alamin/how-to-integrate-jw-player-with-react-or-next-js-a-step-by-step-guide-f67c1b91c05b).

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const VideoPlayer = ({ video }) => {
  const playerRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (playerRef.current && typeof window !== "undefined") {
      window.jwplayer(playerRef.current).setup({
        file: video.sourceUrl,
        width: "100%",
        aspectratio: "16:9",
      });
    }
  }, [video]);

  return <div ref={playerRef}></div>;
};

export default VideoPlayer;
```

```
import VideoPlayer from './VideoPlayer';

const video = {
  sourceUrl: 'https://cdn.jwplayer.com/manifests/EXAMPLE.m3u8',
};

const App = () => {
  return <VideoPlayer video={video} />;
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Looks like the script
`<Script
          id="jw-player"
          strategy="afterInteractive"
          src="https://cdn.jwplayer.com/libraries/YOUR_PLAYER_ID.js"
        ></Script>`
 was not properly set

Comment: @myestery it was the code for nextjs. As mentioned in the article.

Comment: else I have added ```<script src="https://cdn.jwplayer.com/libraries/YOUR_PLAYER_ID.js"></script>
``` in my index.html file with my player_id

Comment: Maybe your react code is executed before `window.jwplayer` is set by the script you load in the `<script>` tag?